# Strange syntax of javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

Yesterday, i saw a javascript file, i have created two issues which they related for syntax of language.

First, what makes this code

```
var result= { 'index': 0 , 'is_check': false };
```

Whats  type of variable is the result ... ?

The second part of code is

```
return { '_teams': teams, 'champions': champions };
```

teams and champions are array.

What the method returns ... ?

Answer (score 10):

- key-value pairs
- hash table/map
- dictionaries
- associative arrays
- and many more...

But in JavaScript, they're simply called [**objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) so don't be confused. And that notation, where it's enclosed in `{}` and values separated by commas, is called [**object literal notation**](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html)

You can check their type using [**typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

```
console.log(typeof result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns object. You can access the elements by using dot operator.